# Joomla - Blog Builder Site

Tags: joomla, blogs, joomla-extensions

Does anybody know if it's possible to create a Blog builder site with Joomla CMS?

There is a lot of extensions to create a personal blog with personal articles. But I wanted to try to make a site like blogger.com but in simple version. So that users can register and add their own blogs and create their articles inside the blogs.
Are there any extensions with this functionality?

I guess the simpliest multiuser blog will be if the site allows registering and creating articles. And then these articles will be moved to one blog page or sorted by categories. But I need to divide the users activity to separate categories (named "blogs").

Answer (score 0):

Try [Zoo](http://yootheme.com/zoo/) or [k2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/k2), both of these allow for blogging functionality.

Comment: I tried K2, thought it will give me what I want. But it just facilitates the personal blogging, not multiuser. Maybe it should be a big project, not for some Joomla beginner practice...